# Problem with react-hooks/exhaustive-deps in useEffect(..., [json.attr])

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to use the react function `useEffect` to do some stuff if the authentication state of my user changes to true.
For this I can request the authState from a context:

```js
const userState = useContext(AuthContext);
```

The `userState` is a json state, which is modified by a reducer function (useReducer(reducer, initialState)) and the magic happens somewhere in the authentication files. The initial state is not null or undefined and the reducer function never let the state be null or undefined

Now I'm in a different index.tsx file of my NextJS code:

```js
...
const userState = useContext(AuthContext);
useEffect(() => {
    if(userState.isAuthenticated) {
        // Doing some stuff
    }
}, [userState.isAuthenticated]);    
...
```

The idea is that everytime when the user auth state changes to true this code will be executed. There are multiple other situations where `userState` changes but the isAuthenticated value stays true (if the user changes his name, his email adress, ...).

But my problem is that eslint with the default nextjs configuration says:

```
174:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'userState'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920

The autofix would set the second argument of the useEffect to `[userState, userState.isAuthenticated]`. But wouldn't that change the behavior of this useEffect? Then my code would be triggered if an user with userState.isAuthenticated=true changes his name or email address, because this would result in a changed userState?

Should I prevent this code ? Should I change it ? Can I just ignore this warning in this cases? I've no idea...

Comment: I have seen many use-cases myself and heard from multiple members from community that its fine to ignore it. You don't have to make it more complex

Answer (score 0):

You can find the explanation for this behavior [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15924#issuecomment-521253636). It's a subtle distinction but I think it matters more for callbacks than for useContext. You can try destructuring `isAuthenticated` and using that in your if-block to see if it makes a difference. I ran sample code similar to yours in my project, and I actually don't get the same suggestion, it only recommends `userState.isAuthenticated` as a dependency for me. So perhaps they fixed this in a later eslint version. For reference, I am using `"eslint": "^8.2.0"`.

So yes, probably fine to ignore in this case.

Comment: I'm using this version too. But do you use eslint with the nextjs preconfigured rules? 
The answere doesn't satisfies me. 

At the moment I'm using always `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` should I continue this?

Comment: No, I am not using nextjs, and disabling exhaustive-deps everywhere is likely a mistake. Can you please reproduce your issue in a code sample I can edit?